# C, detect whether fread will block

Tags: c, blocking, fread, system-calls

In C, is there a way to detect whether a call to libc's `fread` will block? I want to read data from a file descriptor but only if it's available. I'm using GNU+Linux but I'm writing a library so I'm looking for the most portable solution possible.

Comment: man select. Then google or look here in SO for examples.

Comment: @CharlieBurns How do you propose to use `select()` with stdio? One problem is that `fread()` is buffered and `select()` only works on the underlying file descriptor. If using `select` to check if the read would block, he will also need to check whether there is enough data in the buffer - otherwise he'll unnecessarily wait while there is data in the buffer that could be simply picked up. Also, there is no guarantee how many times `fread()` will call the underlying `read()`, and all invocations after the first one will not be preceded by a `select()`.

Comment: @user4815162342, good point. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file pointer points to a non-regular file, and is presumably created with `fdopen()`, one solution is to switch from `fread()` to `read()` and use `select()` to check whether the socket would block. This is portable to all today's Unix-like systems.

If your library receives a file pointer and must work with it throughout (because the API mandates it), the above approach will not work, and neither will calling `select` on the underlying file descriptor. The problem is that due to buffering, `fread()` may not call the underlying `read()` at all, or it may call it more than once. In that case, the only portable solution is to use a blocking `fread()` in a separate thread, and notify the thread that implements the API when the read is done.